# Setup Admin Center without https & username password

Tags: websphere-liberty

Is it possible to setup WebSphere Liberty Admin Center 1.0 using http only without a keystore and a username password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always need to configure the keystore and userid/password for the AdminCenter because the remote Administrative interfaces that the AdminCenter uses, require the user to be authenticated.